# How to download a FULL HTML Google Drive folder page into a variable?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I can not download the complete HTML code from the Google Drive folder to find the ID code for downloading public files from this Google folder. If I open the site and download it through the Mozilla Firefox browser, then it's all in the HTML code. The link to the google drive folder is in the example code below. Everything as an unregistered Google user. These are public files and public folders.

The file, which I know to crawl through the downloaded Mozilla Firefox html code, but not through WGET or Python, has the name:

*piconwhite-220x132-**freeSAT**..........(insignificant remaining part of file name)*

Here is an example of the Python algorithm what I use, but where nothing is obvious (`urllib2` module):

```
        import urllib2

        u_handle = urllib2.urlopen('https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwz6mBA7lUOKZi1nbGdlbzFDZ0U')
        htmlPage = u_handle.read()

        with open('/tmp/test.html','w') as f:
            f.write(htmlPage)
```

If I download a html page using a web browser, the html file size is about 500kB and also contains the above mentioned file to uncover the download code. If I download the webpage through wget or through the Python `urllib2` module, the downloaded html code has a size of only 213kB and does not contain the mentioned file.

BTW, I tried several WGET methods (via linux shell - command line) but there is the same situation - that is, always downloading HTML with a certain number of maximum files from the content (unfortunately, not all files there).

Thank you for all the advice.

P.S.
I'm not a good web developer and I'm looking for a solution to the problem. I'm a developer in other languages and on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

So, I resolved my own problem by downloading a different drive.google webpage as a shortened form of directory / file list. I use this new URL:

```
'https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=0Bwz6mBA7lUOKZi1nbGdlbzFDZ0U#list'
```

Instead of the previous URL:

```
'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwz6mBA7lUOKZi1nbGdlbzFDZ0U'
```

The source code of the "list" site is slightly different, but it has a lot of records (lots of directories or files on drive.google page). So I can see all the files or all the directories that are on the required drive.google website.

Thank you all for helping me or for reading my problem.